# CORBA exception when running from a Mac OS X 10.6 64 bit macbook

Tags: exception, osx-snow-leopard, corba, java-6, ace-tao

I get a weird exception while using CORBA ACE/TAO. I am trying to run a service written in Java that sends/receives messages from clients.
When I run the same code in Windows 7 32-bit it works fine! I exported an executable jar file and tried to run it on my mac, but the problem was still there.
The exception I get is the following:

```
Dec 7, 2011 6:43:52 AM com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL badAddress
WARNING: "IOP00110603: (BAD_PARAM) Bad host address in -ORBInitDef"
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 603  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.NamingSystemException.insBadAddress(NamingSystemException.java:148)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.NamingSystemException.insBadAddress(NamingSystemException.java:166)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.badAddress(CorbalocURL.java:104)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.handleColon(CorbalocURL.java:140)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.handleIIOPColon(CorbalocURL.java:115)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.<init>(CorbalocURL.java:67)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.INSURLHandler.parseURL(INSURLHandler.java:41)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(INSURLOperationImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.ORBInitRefResolverImpl.resolve(ORBInitRefResolverImpl.java:31)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:20)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:22)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1151)
    at ami.ImplRepoClient.<init>(ImplRepoClient.java:23)
    at ami.Famine.initialize(Famine.java:22)
    at ami.Famine.initialize(Famine.java:12)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:45)
Exception in thread "main" org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 603  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.NamingSystemException.insBadAddress(NamingSystemException.java:148)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.NamingSystemException.insBadAddress(NamingSystemException.java:166)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.badAddress(CorbalocURL.java:104)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.handleColon(CorbalocURL.java:140)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.handleIIOPColon(CorbalocURL.java:115)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.CorbalocURL.<init>(CorbalocURL.java:67)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.naming.namingutil.INSURLHandler.parseURL(INSURLHandler.java:41)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.INSURLOperationImpl.operate(INSURLOperationImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.ORBInitRefResolverImpl.resolve(ORBInitRefResolverImpl.java:31)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:20)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:22)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1151)
    at ami.ImplRepoClient.<init>(ImplRepoClient.java:23)
    at ami.Famine.initialize(Famine.java:22)
    at ami.Famine.initialize(Famine.java:12)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:45)
```

In both cases I use java 1.6. The java version in my mac is "build 1.6.0_29-b11-402-10M3527"

Does anybody have any idea of what the problem could be??

Thanks,
Dimos.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Mac can't resolve the address you pass with -ORBInitDef. Try to ping the server manually and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Actually my Mac pings the server successfully!
How can I see the parameter that is passed for ORBInitDef??